# Install salt on fedora

Tags: linux, yum, salt-stack

I trying to install SALT on Fedora:

```
yum install salt-master
```

and It gives me the following Error:

```
Error: Package: salt-2014.1.7-3.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python-jinja2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

When I trying to install python-ninja2, It gives me the following error:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package python-jinja2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What can be the reason for this case? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a actual bug in the RedHat distribution, refer the bugzilla page to get the solution

> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=844710

Comment: and how I enable the optional channel?

Comment: Check for the list of the servers enabled in the package manager, enable the server ID mentioned and then try to update package and install

Comment: Sorry, I new in Fedora. There is any guidelines to do it?

Comment: The section under the Installation of Software contains all that is required, kindly refer http://www.tuxradar.com/content/newbies-guide-fedora-12

Answer (score 0):

To add the optional repository in RHEL for the python-jinja2 package, execute the command:

> sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms